# Extracting DOM and node text using Cypress to provide more information for failing test

Tags: javascript, dom, cypress, accessibility

Im trying to make my test more informative currently it just tells me there's three issues on this page which is great it should fail based on this. I want to extract why it's failed. I want it to be more informative so that when it's reporting it says Here's the failing test, here's the problem, here's the element causing the problem. The information I need seems to be from the nodes in the console output after running the test.

```
describe('Womens T20 Cricket Test',() => {
it('Should log any accessibility failures critical impact on a competition page',() => {
    cy.visit('https://www.skysports.com/cricket/ICC-Womens-World-T20');
    cy.iframe('#sp_message_iframe_758392').find('.sp_message-accept-button').should('be.visible').click()

    cy.injectAxe();
    cy.checkA11y(null, { includedImpacts: ['critical', 'serious', 'moderate']})
    cy.checkA11y({ runOnly: { type: "tag", values: ['wcag2a', 'wcag2aa', ]}})
    cy.contains('a11y error!')
    .parent('td')
    .invoke('text')
    .then((text) => {
    cy.log(text)


    });
  });
});
```

[image: A11y errros]

[image: The information from the nods]

[image: Full screen]

Comment: A side, somewhat unrelated comment, but the example "errors" in the screenshots are not really errors. They're just "best practice" suggestions.  The last screenshot error says "Ensure all page content is contained by landmarks".  There is nothing in [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/) (Accessibility) that **requires** content to be in landmarks. It's a good idea but is not an error.

Comment: This seems awfully close to your previous question. It would be preferable to update that one rather than ask again.

Comment: Perhaps close to the other question it is but its moved on with a bit more knowledge this time. Having said that the last question suggested to fool the script in to passing but then reporting in the console of the IDE. Not ideal if youre trying to run a regression pack and everything seems to be passing when infact it shouldnt be.

Comment: With regards to best practice it's still good to get this kind of infomation recorded somewhere. I am beginning to think that Cypress simply isn't up to the task that testcafe can currently seem to do.